# ServiceDesk парсинг письма отправленного с помощью smtplib

Tags: python, парсер, email, smtplib

Объясню ситуацию: отправляю письмо с помощью `smtplib` (код ниже) на почту `ServiceDesk-а`.
Письмо выглядит следующим образом:

```
Тема: ~Bot~ subject
Тело письма: 
~~OPERATION=AddRequest~~
~~REQUESTER=ФИО~~
```

В параметрах `ServiceDesk-а` прописано, чтобы он парсил информацию, что находится в `~`. Если отправлять письмо из почты (`Outlook` например), то `ServiceDesk` всё парсит нормально, но если через `smtplib` - то никак не парсит, тема так и остаётся `~Bot~ subject` вместо `subject`, и отправитель не подставляется из параметра `REQUESTER`.

Код:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

to = 'servicedesk@my-domain.com'
gmail_user = 'servicedesk@my-domain.com'
gmail_pwd = 'password'
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com", 587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo
smtpserver.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)

subject = "~Bot~ 123"

msg = MIMEText("~~OPERATION=AddRequest~~\r\n~~REQUESTER=FIO~~")
msg['From'] = gmail_user
msg['To'] = to
msg['Subject'] = subject

smtpserver.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg.as_bytes())
smtpserver.close()
```

Пытался изменить кодировку при отправке сообщения, но это не помогло. Так же пробовал другую библиотеку, для отправки писем, что тоже оказалось безуспешным. Возможно, мне не хватает компетенции и я просто не указываю какой-то нужный параметр.

Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема и как её можно исправить. Спасибо!

Comment: попробуй `msg = MIMEText("OPERATION=AddRequest\r\nREQUESTER=FIO", 'plain', 'utf-8')`

Comment: @VirbickasGytautas Спасибо за ответ! Данный способ я пробовал, и, к сожалению, он не сработал